# Gradle shadowjar packages all submodules into a single jar

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-shadow-plugin

Original issue: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/744

I recently converted my project to a multi-module project, but I'm having trouble using shadowjar's **minimize** feature. Here is my project structure:

```
Root project 'shadow-jar-test'
+--- Project ':api'
\--- Project ':core'
```

This is a multi-module project, `core` depends on the `api` module, and both core and api have some third-party dependencies(For example Kotlin std library). And, I implemented these 2 modules in the root project's build script and want to package them into a jar.

The problem is, when I add minimize() to the shadowjar task, it reduces all my code, it seems that it thinks that the subproject is also a third-party dependency.

```
shadowJar {
    relocate 'kotlin', 'lib.kotlin'
    relocate 'org.jetbrains', 'lib.org.jetbrains'

    // minimize will remove the :core and :api module?
    minimize()
}
```

I also tried add exclude statement into minimize:

```
minimize {
        exclude(project(":core"))
        exclude(project(":api"))
}
```

This will indeed package core and api, but the third-party libraries that core and api depend on are still not packaged

#### Shadow Version

7.0.0

#### Gradle Version

7.1

#### Expected Behavior

Properly minimize dependencies

#### Actual Behavior

It also minimized my project code?!

#### Gradle Build Script(s)

I created a example project to reproduce it:
https://github.com/re-ovo/shadow-jar-test

This is the root project build script:
https://github.com/re-ovo/shadow-jar-test/blob/master/build.gradle